# How should looks like a json form with other forms embeded

Tags: json, forms, symfony

I'm using postman to test my json-api. I have to related entities:

Publication:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PublicationRepository")
 */
class Publication
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500)
     */
    private $body;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="publication", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $comments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBody(): ?string
    {
        return $this->body;
    }

    public function setBody(string $body): self
    {
        $this->body = $body;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Comment[]
     */
    public function getComments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    public function addComment(Comment $comment): self
    {
        if (!$this->comments->contains($comment)) {
            $this->comments[] = $comment;
            $comment->setPublication($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeComment(Comment $comment): self
    {
        if ($this->comments->contains($comment)) {
            $this->comments->removeElement($comment);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($comment->getPublication() === $this) {
                $comment->setPublication(null);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CommentRepository")
 *
 */
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $body;

    /**
     * @Assert\Positive
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $likeCount;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLikeCount()
    {
        return $this->likeCount;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $likeCount
     */
    public function setLikeCount($likeCount): void
    {
        $this->likeCount = $likeCount;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Publication", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $publication;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getBody(): ?string
    {
        return $this->body;
    }

    public function setBody(string $body): self
    {
        $this->body = $body;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPublication(): ?Publication
    {
        return $this->publication;
    }

    public function setPublication(?Publication $publication): self
    {
        $this->publication = $publication;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And the Form classes:

PublicationType:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Publication;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PublicationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('body')
            ->add('comments', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => CommentType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
            ]);
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Publication::class,
            'csrf_protection'=> false
        ]);
    }
}
```

CommentType:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;


use App\Entity\Comment;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CommentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('body')
            ->add('publication')
            ->add('likeCount');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Comment::class,
            'csrf_protection'=> false
        ]);
    }
}
```

According  with this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html the Publication form is able to receive a Comment form embeded:

I tried something like this in a postman POST request:

```
{
    "title":"post with comments",
    "body":"some text",
    "comments":[
        {"body":"comment1","likeCount":"5"},
        {"body":"comment2","likeCount":"8"}
        ]
}
```

But I get this:

```
{ "code": 400, "message": "Validation Failed", "errors": { "errors": [ "This form should not contain extra fields." ], "children": { "title": {}, "body": {}, "comments": {} } } }
```

The question is:

How should looks like the json request?

Edit:

I don't think that the trouble is in the root keys, cause before setting the ManyToOne relation I used to submit the form like this:

```
{
    "title":"post with comments",
    "body":"some text"  
}
```

extra info:

This is the  controller code:

```
$form = $this->formFactory->create(PublicationType::class, new Publication());
        $form->submit($request->request->all());
        if (false === $form->isValid()) {
            return $this->viewhandler->createResponse($this->view($form),$request,'json');
        }
        $this->entityManager->persist($form->getData());
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        return new JsonResponse(
            [
                'status' => 'ok',
            ]
        );
```

Comment: care to show the controller function? however, my instinct would be, that the form has a "name" like "publication" and thus might expect data to reside under a publication key or even publication_form. you might have better results, when you create an unnamed form instead. look right **above** the "final thoughts" section on https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes

Comment: just to reiterate, if that wasn't obvious: it's not the embedded form that fails, but the base form (publication). form component complains about "extra" keys, and the keys mentioned are all from the base form (root level keys)

Comment: I edited the question. Any other info?

Comment: probably beside the point but having publication as a field in the comment form seems weird, also maybe you would need allow_add and allow_delete?

Comment: I added allow_add and allow_delete to the configureOptions method in PublicationType and got the same error.

Comment: My bad, I added allow_add wrongly.

Comment: does this mean your problem is solved?

Comment: yeah, I had to do a lite bit more cause I was having issues with the cascade persistance, but it is solved now. As you said, the "This form should not contain extra fields." error was solved adding "allow_add"=true in:  >add('comments', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => CommentType::class,
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
            ));

Comment: nice. glad my persistent nagging steered you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Jakumi was really helpful. I think you should post your suggestion about alow_add and allow_delete as an answer for the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to my first assumption, the error message, actually does provide the fields *that were expected*:

```
{ 
    "code": 400, 
    "message": "Validation Failed", 
    "errors": { 
        "errors": [  
            "This form should not contain extra fields." 
        ], 
        "children": { 
            "title": {}, 
            "body": {}, 
            "comments": {} 
        } 
    } 
}
```

However, that message is not particularly helpful, when exactly those fields are provided and the problem lies in the collection (sub form / sub fields).

The `CollectionType` for the `comments` however doesn't allow adding or removing children (`comments`) unless configured to do so. Adding the [`allow_add`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-add) (and optionally `allow_delete`) fixes the problem.